# Synchronization with semaphore

Tags: c#, multithreading, synchronization

I try to synchronize three threads (named "1", "2" and "3") using `Semaphore` class. They have to print a string into console respecting consequence: 1->2->3. Here is my code:

```
class MyThread
{
    public Thread Thrd;
    static Semaphore sem = new Semaphore(1, 1);
    static int flag = 1;

    public MyThread(string name)
    {
        Thrd = new Thread(this.Run);
        Thrd.Name = name;
        Thrd.Start();
    }

    void Run()
    {
        sem.WaitOne();
        if (Convert.ToInt32(Thrd.Name) == flag)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Thread " + Thrd.Name);
            flag++;
        }
        if (flag == 4)
            flag = 1;
        Thread.Sleep(300);
        sem.Release();
    }
}

class SemaphoreDemo
{
    static void Main()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            MyThread mt1 = new MyThread("1");
            MyThread mt2 = new MyThread("2");
            MyThread mt3 = new MyThread("3");

            mt1.Thrd.Join();
            mt2.Thrd.Join();
            mt3.Thrd.Join();
        }
    }
}
```

But sometimes strings from threads #2 and #3 are not seen. Where is my mistake and how can I fix this problem?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that sometimes a thread will acquire the semaphore out of order, and you don't have any retry logic. Take a look at your `Run` method.

```
void Run()
{
    sem.WaitOne();
    if (Convert.ToInt32(Thrd.Name) == flag)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Thread " + Thrd.Name);
        flag++;
    }
    if (flag == 4)
        flag = 1;
    Thread.Sleep(300);
    sem.Release();
}
```

Now, what happens if the thread named "3" acquires the semaphore first? `flag` is equal to `1`, so the conditional code won't be executed. The thread will just sleep for 300 milliseconds and then exit. If you want this to work, you have to make the thread retry:

```
void Run()
{
    bool success = false;
    while (!success)
    {
        sem.WaitOne();
        if (Convert.ToInt32(Thrd.Name) == flag)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Thread " + Thrd.Name);
            flag++;
            success = true;
        }
        sem.Release();
        if (!success)
        {
            // let somebody else try
            Thread.Sleep(300);
        }
    }
}
```

That will make your sample work as expected.

I suspect that this is just an exercise to see how threading and semaphores work. Note, however, that a Mutex is usually more appropriate than a Semaphore with a maximum count of 1.

Note also that there are other ways to make threads execute in sequence, although truthfully if you're going to sequence your threads then you probably don't need more than one thread. Unless those threads are doing other things and they only need to sequence once--or infrequently.